# Is a grounding rod required for my sub panel?

Tags: code-compliance

I have 100' of 10/3 UF wire running from a double pole 30amp breaker to my shed where it meets a double pole 20amp panel where the ground and neutral are separate and it feeds 5 outlets and 2 lights do I have to add a grounding rod or is it okay the way it is?

Comment: What does the code say where you are?

Comment: Can't find a clear answer everything says no your not supposed to put UF In conduit no matter how I word it same results

Comment: I am probably missing something, but UF in conduit has nothing to do with your question.  Ground rods and conduit are two different things.  Even with conduit you will need ground rods for a detached building.

Comment: How many breakers can fit in the panel at the shed?

Comment: You should check to find out your local authority accepts, rejects, or modifies the exception to NEC 250.32(A).

Answer (score 4):

For a sub-panel in a detached structure, you need 2 ground rods spaced at least 6' apart in a detached structure in most jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.  If you are simply running a 15A or 20A circuit, and that includes a shared neutral aka MWBC (Multi-Wire Branch Circuit), then you do not need ground rods for a single circuit.

If you have a subpanel in the shed, you absolutely do need a set of ground rods, or UFER ground.